# Webpack fail when running next build in gitlab ci (works fine locally) typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, next.js, gitlab-ci

Trying to setup a ci/cd for the frontend team (I did not work on the frontend code directly, so I may be missing some things).

The frontend is made with next.js 13 and typescript.

I created a dockerfile which looks like this.

```
FROM node:16.17.1-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:16.17.1-alpine as production

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This works fine when I try building on my computer (MacBook M1 latest OS)

But this doesn't work on Gitlab CI. It gives me the "can't resolve module ...." error. Mainly with the @components module in the code.(not a problem locally btw)

My gitlab ci file looks like this (left some part out for security purposes)

```
build_and_push:
  only:
    - main
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION) $DOCKER_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$REPO_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TITLE --file Dockerfile.staging .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$REPO_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TITLE
```

And here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "utils/*"
      ],
      "@lib/*": [
        "lib/*"
      ],
      "@services/*": [
        "services/*"
      ]
    },
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the path has been added already and produced no problem when building locally.

here is the next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['images.unsplash.com'],
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true
  },
  // typescript:{
  //   ignoreBuildErrors: true
  // }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I am not sure what is causing the CI pipeline to not work. Has anyone faced this issue before?